# Install Genymotion in a different location

Tags: software-installation, genymotion

When I try installing it using `sudo` it says:

```
Installing to folder [/opt/genymobile/genymotion]
```

Anyone knows how can I change the path?

I also tried opening a terminal as root and changing its path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed Genymotion to play CoC several months ago. I got it to live in the Documents folder. The way you do this is install it first, then use the command:

```
mv (folder to move) (new destination)
```

Simple as that!